# Edit .PSD File on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I have a .PSD file which needs to edited. It contains just two layers, one an image and the other a text layer. I want to edit the text layer. I read online Photoshop touch doesn't let you edit .psd files.

Is there any way to do this on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [iDraw for iOS](http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/) ([$8.99 on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idraw/id363317633)).

It's the only app for iOS that I ever came across that claims to be able to import (and export) PSD files. I haven't (yet) tried iDraw myself, so I can't say how well it works, but it looks promising.